# Some Browser api is missing in SSG

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, next.js, static-site-generation

I deployed a project using Next.js (13v) static export (SSG) and hosted the generated files on AWS S3.

The project uses the Clipboard API, and it works in the local environment, but not in the production environment.

Upon inspection, I noticed that the `clipboard` property is missing in the `window.navigator` object in the production environment.

Is it possible that certain browser APIs cannot be used in statically generated files?

Comment: Maybe your browser is the issue, rather than Next.js. Take a look at the compatibility table [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/user-registration-authentication-strapi-next-js).